# FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager,

Tags: c#, ado.net, oracle.manageddataaccess

I am trying to connect to Oracle database from .NET Core 3.1 using ADO.NET, here's my code:

```
private OracleConnection GetOracleConnection()
{
    string conString = "Data Source=Q550.adr.XXXX.com;Persist Security,Info=True;User ID=XXXX;Password=CCC39";
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(conString);
    return con;
}
```

but when this function executes following exception occured at line number 2

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for
> 'OracleInternal.Common.ProviderConfig' threw an exception**
>
> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager,   Version=4.0.2.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot
> find the file specified.

Can anyone tell me what's happening?

Comment: Try this : Go to project properties and uncheck prefer 32 bit.

Comment: By any chance, do you refer the ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings or added ConfigurationManager in your namespace? In .net core, you need to include the System.Configuration as a package to use the ConfigurationManager object to access the AppSettings and ConnectionStrings.

Comment: alternatively , you can `Install-Package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` from nuget

Comment: "prefer 32 bit" is unchecked (by default when creating the project) and doesn't solve the problem. Installing System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager as you suggest does it.

Comment: exactly same problem here when trying to connect to MySQL

Comment: Installing the package doesn't help when deploying because the dll is not included in the build

Answer (score 48):

You can Install System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager from Nuget

```
Install-Package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
```

This problem is a known issue as you can see here and the recommended solution is nuget package

https://github.com/pusher/pusher-websocket-dotnet/issues/34

Comment: For MySQL I needed this ,and also System.Management, no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding a reference to NuGet package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, but the latest version of this library (7.0) doesn't contain the ConfigurationManager anymore. So then it still doesn't compile. After a lot of seaching, I figured out I had to include version 4.5 of the NuGet package.

Comment: I just double check using dotPeek, the dll version 7.0.0.0 for .NETCoreApp v.6.0 indeed contains the class ConfigurationManager.

Comment: I tried 7.0, no good, downgraded to 4.5, success! Thanks!